# How to get value of put() stream pointer in c++

Tags: c++, file, pointers

How can I get the value of put() stream pointer...(in c++)
I mean the address of the location where the next element has to be written.

tellp() only gives relative position not absolute one..

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`seekp()` sets the position, does not get it.

`tellp()` gets the absolute location of the put pointer.